# Are parameters in snowflake connection URL case sensitive?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I attempted to connect to Snowflake using the jdbc connection url with database name. Yet, even with a lowercase database name, the connection still goes through. Is the database name case sensitive in the connection url?

Database name in snowflake: SAMPLE
Database name in the url: sample

Comment: Hi - it’s not a question of whether the parameters are case-sensitive, it’s a question of whether the Snowflake objects they are referencing are case-sensitive. Have a look at this: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-connect-to-a-case-sensitive-database-using-JDBC

Comment: I went with the 1st approach. The connection goes through irrespective of the case.